# Unexpected DateTime behaviour in PHP

Tags: datetime, php-7

Here is a a simple piece of code where I am trying to convert a
string into a DateTime object. Since the input string is invalid
I expect the "Error" print.

```
<?php
$expiryDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/02/20');
if (!$expiryDate) {
    echo "Error";
    return;
}
$expiryDate = $expiryDate->format('d/m/Y');
echo $expiryDate;
?>
```

However I get:

```
01/02/0020
```

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the result of `date_create_from_format` formatted to the parse format with the original date string, and if they don't match, there was an error:

```
$input_date = '01/02/20';
$format = 'd/m/Y';
$expiryDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input_date);
if (!$expiryDate || ($expiryDate = $expiryDate->format($format)) != $input_date) {
    echo "Error" . PHP_EOL;
}
else {
    echo $expiryDate . PHP_EOL;
}

$input_date = '01/02/2020';
$format = 'd/m/Y';
$expiryDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $input_date);
if (!$expiryDate || ($expiryDate = $expiryDate->format($format)) != $input_date) {
    echo "Error" . PHP_EOL;
}
else {
    echo $expiryDate . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Error
01/02/2020
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/otLWR)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check if given date string is in valid format:

```php
<?php
$dateString = '01/02/20';
$isValid = preg_match("/^\\d{2}\/\\d{2}\/\\d{4}$/", $dateString);
if (!$isValid) {
    echo "Error";
    return;
}
$expiryDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateString);

if (!$expiryDate) {
    echo "Error";
    return;
}
$expiryDate = $expiryDate->format('d/m/Y');
echo $expiryDate;
```

Working code example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11bd4863bd02b2ee9a02f490ca4e594dc0c33866

Comment: That defeats the whole point of using createFromFormat :-(

Comment: What're you trying to achieve? `01/02/20` is a valid input for `createFromFormat`.

Comment: @bravemaster  It shouldn’t be valid. “Y” is the four digit year. “20” is two digits. It doesn’t fit the specified format